# SphinxQL match this field OR this field

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

My database contains a table with a field called "tag".

I'd like to get all rows where "tag" field matches "white tiger" OR "brown lion".

I tried the following syntax but not working:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH('@tag white tiger|brown lion');
```

Thankf for your help!

Comment: Ok, I managed to find how it works, just add parenthesis:
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH('@tag ((white tiger)|(brown lion))');

Comment: You shoudl add that as an Answer. Then accept your own answer. It wont get you any points, but will mark the question as "Answered" so that other people will know.